# Magento 2 : How to show add to cart button in out of stock?

Tags: magento2.2.2, out-of-stock, list.phtml

I want to show add to cart button block in my list.phtml even a product is out of stock.
I do not want to enable **back orders** too.

How can i do this?

OR

May i know from which file checking the stock status and hide the add cart block?

Posting what i tried is no point here to drag the question.So i did not post it.I just want to get an idea to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: can you check : https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-displaydisable-out-of-stock-product-by-your-own/

Comment: @PrashantPatel thanks you, i can display the product in list.phtml.but i cannot display the cart button section when the product is out of stock.What my purpose is i want to show the add to quote button when the stock is zero.

Comment: can you find this line and comment in list.phtml "$_product->isSaleable()"

Comment: thank you.its working,you may post this as answer.i will accept it